# View free disk space of Hyper-V

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

Is there any easy way to view Hyper-V's free disk space? I have a Windows 2012 R2 Server that is hosting the Hyper-V manager and I need to know the amount of free disk space. Is there a way to view it with the manager? Is there a way to view disk space on the server itself without running a script?

Comment: To be clear, are you just wanting the free disk space of the Hyper-V host? Does the host have local disks that you are using for storage? Does it use a SAN?

Comment: Yes, I want to view how much free disk space is on the Hyper-V host. Currently it's just local disks but we will have a SAN attached later, probably by ISCSI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Windows Performance Monitor](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/03/16/windows-performance-monitor-disk-counters-explained.aspx) to remotely connect to and view data.

Click Start , click in the Start Search box, type perfmon , and press ENTER

Click on Performance Monitor on the Left

Delete the current process

Click Add, and browse to another computer. You will need to be on the same domain as the computer you want to connect to.

Under LogicalDisk select Free Megabytes. Select . Click Add.

Click OK.

Select Report under Graph Type. This will show the free disk space per volume.